# Why casting (Object)null result to not null?

Tags: java, variadic-functions

I use java 7, and I create a varargs method

```
public class JavaApplicationTest {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        addBundleMessage("b", Integer.SIZE, "key", (Object) null);
    }

    public static void addBundleMessage(String bundleName, Integer severity, String key, Object... params) {
        if (params == null)
            System.out.println("params Is null");
        else
            System.out.println("Params not null");
    }
}
```

If I don't cast the object, the IDEs Netbeans or Eclipse complains but it compiles :

> non-varargs call of varags method with inexact argument type for last
>   parameter

When **No cast** : it display **params Is null**

When I cast null to **(Object)** it display **Params not null**

When I cast null to **(Object[])** it display **params Is null**

**Is it normal behavior ?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that is "normal" behaviour.

The confusion comes from varargs being bolted on to the language later and being implemented using an array as the "real parameter" to hold the variable number of parameters.

```
public static void addBundleMessage(String bundleName, Integer severity,
   String key, Object... params) {
```

is almost the same as

```
public static void addBundleMessage(String bundleName, Integer severity,
   String key, Object[] params) {
```

and under the hoods, the params are passed wrapped as an Object[].

However, you still have the option to pass in that array yourself.

If you use `(Object[]) null`, you get a parameter (that is null).

If you use `(Object) null`, it uses the varargs method, so it passes in an array to hold the parameters (of which there is only one which is null).

For "normal use" of a varargs method, `params` will never be null. The "worst" you can get is an empty array (if there are no arguments at all).

Answer (score 0):

The casting won't do anything to the null, it will just help the compiler choose between the overloaded methods.
As you are using a multi-param method, the params will be an array so your null test on it is not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

> When No cast : it display params Is null

The varargs are null in this case, so you get a null

> When I cast null to (Object) it display Params not null

The varargs contains one object (per your casting) which is null

> When I cast null to (Object[]) it display params Is null

The varargs **are** the Object[] you passed, which is null

Answer (score 0):

Without the cast is the same as with a cast to `Object[]`. You are passing a null argument array, so `params` is null.

When you cast the null to `Object`, you are passing a single null argument, so `params` is not null, it is instead an `Object[1]`, whose only element is null.