# weaponCombinations all item id's

Tags: java

I'm working on having weapons weapon restrictions when players want to fight one another in an arena.

My combinations work but my 'all weapons' doesn't work. Weapon restrictions is you choose which weapons are allowed & which ones aren't.

Code:

```
public static final WeaponCombination[] WEAPON_COMBINATIONS;

static {
    WEAPON_COMBINATIONS = new WeaponCombination[] { 
            new WeaponCombination("@cya@All", (Weapon[]) null),
            new WeaponCombination("@red@Whip + Staff of Gods", new Weapon(300), new Weapon(302)), 
            new WeaponCombination("@red@Swords Only", new Weapon(306, 308, 310, 312)),
            new WeaponCombination("@red@Axe's Only", new Weapon(360, 362, 364, 366)) };
}
```

I forgot my weapon class:

```
package rezzion.model.minigames.duel;

public class Weapon {
    private int[] items;

    public Weapon(int... items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public int[] getItems() {
        return items;
    }
}
```

The all should account for all id's Every weapon in the game (1-3905). Anyone know why (Weapons[]) null doesn't work?
  I don't really want to type out all 3905 id's into a string...

Comment: If you could make the question more generic it would be nice.

Comment: How does it not work? Do you get an error? How does your logic in WeaponCombination look?

Comment: It count's as no item id's. Meaning no Item's can be used. But when I specify an item it works.

Comment: are you using `if (secondArg instanceof null)` in WeaponCombination? Why are you trying to cast null?

Comment: Perhaps this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097664/why-casting-objectnull-result-to-not-null

Comment: I forgot something that may have made this thread a bit harder to understand. I added it to the post. @ Ron not really I've already tried what that post suggests.

Answer (score 0):

What the `(Weapon[]) null` means would be that the parameter you are sending will be null. So your constructor in the `WeaponCombination` class would be `(String, null)` rather than `(String, Weapon...)` . This means that you are effectively not passing any weapons into the class. A possible workaround is to check for null in your `WeaponCombination` class and if you get it then you should include all the weapons. Or you could cycle through all the item ids in a for loop and create an array of weapons that way